# Scala currying example in the tutorial is confusing me

Tags: scala

I'm reading a bit about Scala currying [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html) and I don't understand this example very much:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

1. What is the `[B]` in square brackets? Why is it in brackets? The `B` after the colon is the return type right? What is the type?

It looks like this method has 2 parameter lists: one with a parameter named `z` and one with a parameter named `op` which is a function.

2. `op` looks like it takes a function `(B, A) => B)`. What does the right side mean? It returns `B`?

And this is apparently how it is used:

```
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
val res = numbers.foldLeft(0)((m, n) => m + n)
print(res) // 55
```

What is going on? Why wasn't the [`B`] needed when called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the `[B]` in square brackets?

A type parameter (that's also known as "generics" if you've seen something like Java before)

> Why is it in brackets?

Because type parameters are written in brackets, that's just Scala syntax. Java, C#, Rust, C++ use angle brackets `< >` for similar purposes, but since arrays in Scala are accessed as `arr(idx)`, and (unlike Haskell or Python) Scala does not use `[ ... ]` for list comprehensions, the square brackets could be used for type parameters, and there was no need for angular brackets (those are more difficult to parse anyway, especially in a language which allows almost arbitrary names for infix and postfix operators).

> The `B` after the colon is the return type right?

Right.

> What is the type?

Ditto. The return type is `B`.

> It looks like this method has 2 parameter lists: one with a parameter named `z` and one with a parameter named `op` which is a function.

This method has a type parameter `B` and two argument lists for value arguments, correct. This is done to simplify the type inference: the type `B` can be inferred from the first argument `z`, so it does not have to be repeated when writing down the lambda-expression for `op`. This wouldn't work if `z` and `op` were in the same argument list.

> `op` looks like it takes a function `(B, A) => B`.

The type of the argument `op` is `(B, A) => B`, that is, `Function2[B, A, B]`, a function that takes a `B` and an `A` and returns a `B`.

> What does the right side mean? It returns `B`?

Yes.

> What is going on?

`m` acts as accumulator, `n` is the current element of the list. The fold starts with integer value `0`, and then accumulates from left to right, adding up all numbers. Instead of `(m, n) => m + n`, you could have written `_ + _`.

> Why wasn't the [`B`] needed when called?

It was inferred from the type of `z`. There are many other cases where the generic type cannot be inferred automatically, then you would have to specify the return type explicitly by passing it as an argument in the square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala documentation that `A` type (sometimes `A1`) is often the placeholder for a collection's element type. So if you have...

```
List('c','q','y').foldLeft( //....etc.
```

...then `A` becomes the reference for `Char` because the list is a `List[Char]`.

The `B` is a placeholder for a 2nd type that `foldLeft` will have to deal with. Specifically it is the type of the 1st parameter as well as the type of the `foldLeft` result. Most of the time you actually don't need to specify it when `foldLeft` is invoked because the compiler will infer it. So, yeah, it could have been...

```
numbers.foldLeft[Int](0)((m, n) => m + n)
```

...but why bother? The compiler knows it's an `Int` and so does anyone reading it (anyone who knows Scala).

`(B, A) => B` is a function that takes 2 parameters, one of type `B` and one of type `A`, and produces a result of type `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called polymorphism. The function can work on multiple types and you sometimes want to give a parameter of what type will be worked with. Basically the B is a type parameter and can either be given explicitly as a type, which would be `Int` and then it should be given in square brackets or implicitly in parentheses like you did with the `0`. Read about polymorphism here [Scala polymorphism](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html)